# Cant fully understand how to works array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, null

Sorry, guys. But I cant understand why I constantly get a ReferenceError. Below a simple array code when you enter two digits in console.log shows numbers between them divided like **% 2** .
But when I try to add capability of eliminate : null, 'string', and etc. it shows a ReferenceError by
**arr.push(i);**

**for example**

```
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++){
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      if (i === null) {
        alert('qwerty');
      }
    }
   }
      arr.push(i);
      return arr;
    };
```

**This is original code. it works but without filter**

```
let first = +prompt('Please enter first number:');
let second = +prompt('Please enter second number ');

function arrRange(min, max) {
  let arr = [];
  
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) 
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
   
  arr.push(i);
  return arr;
};

console.log(arrRange(first ,second ))
```

Comment: Your `arr.push(i);` is outside of your for loop and `i` is only a variable within the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are pushing `i` to the `arr` in a wrong place. You just mixed the scopes of function.

There you have a simple solution:

```
for (let i = min; i <= max; i++){
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      if (i === null) {
        alert('qwerty');
      }
        arr.push(i);
    }
    
   }
     
      return arr;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example i is out of loop that is why you get Reference error.
You cant fix it just by transfer your push method inside loop

`for (let i = min; i <= max; i++){
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      if (i === null) {
        alert('qwerty');
      }
    }
    arr.push(i); 
   }
      // arr.push(i); out of loop and i here doesn't exist 
      return arr;
    };`